# App crashes in catch in doInBackground in AsynkTask when sending email

Tags: android, android-asynctask

my problem ist, that my app which starts a service crashes in the catch block in doInBackground of the AsynkTask while sending an email. It allmost goes good, but for example when I get a connection timeout or other connection errors, then I can catch the exception, but the service crashes and restarts after a couple of minutes. In this case a check of the internet connection before starting the AsynkTask is not helpfull.

The AsynkTask to send the email is started by the AlarmManager.

**Why is the app/service ending/crashing?** I am catching the exception! Can anyone give me a hint?

Here is the relevant code:

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Message, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Message... msg) {
        try {
            Transport.send(msg[0]);
            log.info("### - Mail sent");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String a = e.getMessage();
            Log.e("SendMail_Loc", "Error: " + a);
            log.error("Error: " + a,e);
        }
        return "Executed";
    }      

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

And this is cought exception:

```
 2014-03-06 11:13:00,252 -  [ERROR::de.egi.location.track.SendMail::de.egi.location.track.SendMail$LongOperation] - Error: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.strato.de, port: 25
   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.xxxx.de, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to smtp.xxxx.de/xx.xxx.145.133 (port 25):  connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at de.egi.location.track.SendMail$LongOperation.doInBackground(SendMail.java:91)
    at de.egi.location.track.SendMail$LongOperation.doInBackground(SendMail.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to smtp.xxxx.de/xx.xx.145.133 (port 25): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:785)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Have you set Internet permission in manifest file?

Comment: check your mail id from which your sending the mail its a smtp server exception

Comment: Yes, the internet permissions are set. Mostly it works fine. Only if I get an exception then I can log teh exception in the catch block and then it crashes.
Nothing to do with mail id. In this case it was a bad connection with a connection timeout as exception.

Comment: My question is not to find the error why the exception is comming up. That I know.

**The question is why is the app/service crashing after a caught exception in doInBackground of the AsynkTask?**

Comment: So I investigated a lot and searched over Google and so on, and found questions and comments about this behavior.
My conclusion is, that although the exceptions are catched in doInBackground of AsynkTask, the service often crashes/ends, when the error had something with internet (HTTP) or email (SMTP)! It might be an android error?!